# Changing AccessDataSource to SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to change my database from Access to MS SQL and I've got the database ready and everything. I've gone around my website and changed the IDs for each data source to SqlDataSource(number here) and then changed each control that uses the property "DataSourceID" to reflect the name change. However, when I try to open my website, it says it is still looking for AccessDataSource1. Here is some of my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TravelJoansDBSQLConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 8 * FROM [Table2]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" ItemStyle-CssClass="picTableStyle"
    DataKeyField="ID">
    <ItemStyle></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <br /><br />
        <table>
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Places.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>'>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="1px" Width="220px" Height="180px" ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Image") %>' /><br /></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="picCaptionStyle"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Caption") %>' /></td>

                <td>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"~/Places.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>'>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" class="picTitleStyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BlogTitle") %>' /><br /></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDate", "{0:MMMMMMMMM dd, yyyy}") %>' /><br /><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="picBodyText" runat="server" Text='<%# Limit(Eval("PicText"), 400)+"..." %>' />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%#"~/Places.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID")%>' Text="[Read More]" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Again, when I try to run my website based on this code, I get the error "The DataSourceID of 'DataList1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'AccessDataSource1' could not be found." Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clean then rebuild. Try a ctrl+F in all files to see if "AccessDataSource1" is lingering somewhere.

Comment: If you type it as an answer, I can mark it. I missed a couple of references apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a clean then rebuild. You can also try a Ctrl+F in all files to see if "AccessDataSource1" is lingering somewhere.